# Google Maps Multiple Custom Markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

So I'm trying to learn how to make a google map. I have very little understanding of javascript but am trying to learn here.

I referenced a code online and I got to the point where I sort of understand how to add locations, marker, and a infowindow but I'm trying to figure out how to add multiple custom icons for each marker.

Thanks for the help.

```
function initialize() {

        //add map, the type of map
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 6,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.7749295, -122.4194155),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });

        //add locations
        var locations = [
            ['San Francisco: Power Outage', 37.7749295, -122.4194155],
            ['Sausalito', 37.8590937, -122.4852507],
            ['Sacramento', 38.5815719, -121.4943996],
            ['Soledad', 36.424687, -121.3263187],
            ['Shingletown', 40.4923784, -121.8891586]
        ];

        //declare marker call it 'i'
        var marker, i;

        //declare infowindow
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

        //add marker to each locations
        for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
                map: map,
            });

            //click function to marker, pops up infowindow
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                return function() {
                    infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                }
            })(marker, i));
        }
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are multiple ways, the easiest is to set the icon-property of the marker to a URL of an image you want to appear as marker.

sample:

```
//modified array with icon-URLs
var locations = [
            ['San Francisco: Power Outage', 37.7749295, -122.4194155,'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_purple.png'],
            ['Sausalito', 37.8590937, -122.4852507,'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png'],
            ['Sacramento', 38.5815719, -121.4943996,'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_green.png'],
            ['Soledad', 36.424687, -121.3263187,'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png'],
            ['Shingletown', 40.4923784, -121.8891586,'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_yellow.png']
        ];



//inside the loop
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
                map: map,
                icon: locations[i][3]
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var locations = [
        ['San Francisco: Power Outage', 37.7749295, -122.4194155],
        ['Sausalito', 37.8590937, -122.4852507],
        ['Sacramento', 38.5815719, -121.4943996],
        ['Soledad', 36.424687, -121.3263187],
        ['Shingletown', 40.4923784, -121.8891586]
    ];
```

Locations represents an array of districts followed by their posicón specifically by its latitude and longitude , so they will be positioned on the map of google , not always latitude and longitude in this way be sent , so you can receive database or json . I hope I've helped.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div id="map"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript">          
     function initialize() {
         //add map, the type of map
           var mapOptions = {
               zoom: 5,
               draggable: true,
               animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
               mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
               center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.4964302,-0.1331412), // area location
               styles:[{"stylers":[{"saturation":-100},{"gamma":1}]},{"elementType":"labels.text.stroke","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"poi.business","elementType":"labels.text","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"poi.business","elementType":"labels.icon","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"poi.place_of_worship","elementType":"labels.text","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"poi.place_of_worship","elementType":"labels.icon","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"water","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"saturation":50},{"gamma":0},{"hue":"#50a5d1"}]},{"featureType":"administrative.neighborhood","elementType":"labels.text.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#333333"}]},{"featureType":"road.local","elementType":"labels.text","stylers":[{"weight":0.5},{"color":"#333333"}]},{"featureType":"transit.station","elementType":"labels.icon","stylers":[{"gamma":1},{"saturation":50}]}]
           };
           var mapElement = document.getElementById('map');
           var map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, mapOptions);

         //add locations
             var locations = [
                 ['London office', 51.4964302,-0.1331412,'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png'],
                 ['Sausalito', 37.8590937, -122.4852507,'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png'],
                 ['Sacramento', 38.5815719, -121.4943996,'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_green.png'],
                 ['Soledad', 36.424687, -121.3263187,'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png'],
                 ['Shingletown', 40.4923784, -121.8891586,'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_yellow.png']
             ];
             //declare marker call it 'i'
             var marker, i;
             //declare infowindow
             var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
             //add marker to each locations
             for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
                 marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                     position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
                     map: map,
                     icon: locations[i][3]
             });
             //click function to marker, pops up infowindow
             google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                 return function() {
                     infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
                     infowindow.open(map, marker);
                 }
             })(marker, i));
         }
     }
     google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
  </script>
```