# Google Maps API Custom Markers

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-api, google-maps-markers

I am trying to create a map using custom marker icons of various shapes and colors.  I have the code working such that I can use any single marker for all locations, but not different markers for different locations.  I am currently programming this into a FileMaker Pro solution however I'm writing the code in Javascript.  I am new to Javascript and I'm picking things up as I go, but below is the code I have so far:

```
var concus = 'Dropbox/FileMaker Pro Files/FileMaker Pro Contract Bid Files/Images/red_customer.png';
var rencus = 'Dropbox/FileMaker Pro Files/FileMaker Pro Contract Bid Files/Images/purple_customer.png';
var sercus = 'Dropbox/FileMaker Pro Files/FileMaker Pro Contract Bid Files/Images/green_customer.png';
var connon = 'Dropbox/FileMaker Pro Files/FileMaker Pro Contract Bid Files/Images/red_noncustomer.png';
var rennon = 'Dropbox/FileMaker Pro Files/FileMaker Pro Contract Bid Files/Images/purple_noncustomer.png';
var sernon = 'Dropbox/FileMaker Pro Files/FileMaker Pro Contract Bid Files/Images/green_noncustomer.png';

var imagenum;

var markers = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data[i].latitude, data[i].longitude);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: latlng, map: map, icon: markerimage[i], title:data[i].label, info:data[i].info});

  markers.push(marker);
}
```

"markerimage" after "icon: " is the array which stores the values "concus, rencus, sercus...etc" from my database. If i replace "markerimage" with any of the specific ones the script works and shows me a map with all the locations on them.  If I use markerimage I only get a map with nothing on it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Zak

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps Multiple Custom Markers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16266772/google-maps-multiple-custom-markers)

Comment: i'm trying to use different markers for different locations, not the same one for multiple locations.

Comment: Did you look at that the answer to that example?  Each marker has a different icon.  Or do you mean something different by "different markers for different locations"?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var iconBase = 'Dropbox/FileMaker Pro Files/FileMaker Pro Contract Bid Files/Images/';

var icons = {
  concus: {
    icon: iconBase + 'red_customer.png'
  },
  rencus: {
    icon: iconBase + 'purple_customer.png'
  },
  sercus: {
    icon: iconBase + 'green_customer.png'
  },
  connon: {
    icon: iconBase + 'red_noncustomer.png'
  },
  rennon: {
    icon: iconBase + 'purple_noncustomer.png'
  },
  sernon: {
    icon: iconBase + 'green_noncustomer.png'
  }
};


function addMarker(feature) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: feature.position,
    icon: icons[feature.type].icon,
    map: map
  });
}
```

Comment: I think I understand what you did, however I had a question about "feature.type"  Is that where "concus, rencus...etc" would go? or where the loop counter would go?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/j7Cyu/     the really big array at the beginning stores the lat, long, and label information for the info window when you click on a marker