# Show users coordinates and trigger event

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

I am using the Geolocation Marker Script from the Google Maps Utilities Library V3 in order to display the position of a user.

What I want to achieve (I am a newbie to the Google Maps API!) is:

- have the users current coordinates displayed (e.g. in a simple CSS container somewhere on the page)
- connect an event to a marker. I should be triggered when the user is close.

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display coordinates to the user, you would need a reference to a DOM Element. Then it's a simple matter of updating the content.

## HTML On the Page

```
<div id="UserCoordinates">Waiting on GPS Position ...</div>
```

## In Script

```
google.maps.event.addListener(GeoMarker, 'position_changed', function() {
  var UserPosition = this.getPosition();
  var DisplayElement = document.getElementById('UserCoordinates');
  if(UserPosition === null) {
    DisplayElement.innerHTML = 'Waiting on GPS Position...';
  } else {
    DisplayElement.innerHTML =
        'Current Position: ' + UserPosition.toUrlValue();
  }
});
```

This will show the user their current position as it changes. If you are going to continue using a full screen map, you'll probably want to implement the `UserCoordinates` div as a map control. The [API Reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls) has a good overview and multiple examples on this.

## Display an info window when the user is within X meters of a location

This is a little tricky because there are multiple scenarios to handle and you don't want the infowindow opening repeatedly as they move within your radius.

### Distance calculation

I see you have a distance function in your code, but I recommend using the one in the [Spherical Geometry library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#spherical) of the API. You just have to specifically load the library with your api script tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry&sensor=true_or_false">
</script>
```

Then you need to add to the `position_changed` event handler:

```
var IsWithinRadius = false; //assume they start outside of the circle
var RadiusInMeters = 1000; //within 1 km
var LocationOfInterest = map.getCenter();
google.maps.event.addListener(GeoMarker, 'position_changed', function() {
  var UserPosition = this.getPosition();
  var DisplayElement = document.getElementById('UserCoordinates');
  if(UserPosition === null) {
    DisplayElement.innerHTML = 'Waiting on GPS Position...';
    IsWithinRadius = false; //you don't know where they are
  } else {
    DisplayElement.innerHTML =
        'Current Position: ' + UserPosition.toUrlValue();
    var IsCurrentPositionInRadius =
        Math.abs(google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(
            UserPosition, LocationOfInterest)) <= RadiusInMeters;
    var JustEnteredRadius = !IsWithinRadius && IsCurrentPositionInRadius;
    IsWithinRadius = IsCurrentPositionInRadius;
    if(JustEnteredRadius) {
      //trigger action here.
      alert("Within raidus");
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Awesome, Chad! Thank you so much. But I there is still one thing I don't understand. How can I apply your "within-radius" skript to multiple markers like this one: 
  var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(49.455,11.075),
  map: map,
  draggable: false
  });

Say, I'd like event1 to trigger when the user is within a radius of 100 meters around marker1, event2 if within 100 meters around marker2 ...

Comment: I am trying to make a treasure hunt for kids containing multiple locations with connected events...

Comment: Assuming you have an array of locations, you would just loop through that array in the event and do similar checks. The `IsWithinRaidus` and `LocationOfInterest` variables would both need to be properties specific to each location.

Comment: That makes perfect sense but I've got to admit that I have no idea how to do this... I tried the script for multiple custom markers here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16266772/google-maps-multiple-custom-markers) but can't get it to work. And even if I could I still wouldn't know how to loop through the locations and check if the user is close... Help!

Comment: You should start a new question for this. Make sure to post what you've already tried.

Comment: Ok, did that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19741656/google-maps-api-detect-if-user-is-close-to-a-location-out-of-an-array-and-tri